# NSBrowserDelegate not asking for preview view controller

Tags: appkit

I'm implementing an NSBrowser in Swift and want to display a preview view controller when certain leaf items are selected in the browser.

I've implemented the `func browser(browser: NSBrowser, previewViewControllerForLeafItem item: AnyObject)` method, but it never gets called.

I'm also implementing the following delegate methods:

```
func browser(sender: NSBrowser, numberOfRowsInColumn column: Int)
func browser(sender: NSBrowser, willDisplayCell cell: AnyObject, atRow row: Int, column: Int)
```

Comment: Did you implement `func browser(browser: NSBrowser, isLeafItem item: AnyObject?) -> Bool`?

Comment: @Willeke I tried, but it never gets called. So I've been setting the .leaf property of NSBrowserCell in the willDisplayCell:... delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`previewViewControllerForLeafItem` needs an item. The documentation of NSBrowser could be better but it says about `previewViewControllerForLeafItem`:

> This method is called only if the delegate implements the item data source methods.

The item data source methods are `rootItemForBrowser`, `numberOfChildrenOfItem`, `child ofItem`, `isLeafItem` and `objectValueForItem`.

Comment: Thanks, I did see this in the documentation but couldn't work out what the requisite methods were.